# Why is the function being called multiple times in a loop?

Tags: java, regex, loops, parsing, processing

I've made a graphical calculator app using the Processing Development Environment and have incorporated a Java `Operation` class. Then I called instances of the `Operation` class in my main file - calculator.pde. **When I call the method on the multiple instances, conditionally, it prints output from the method multiple times because of the loop and conditional from which the method is called.**

Here's the `calculate()` method of `Operation` class:

```Java
String calculate() {
    int operationIndex = userInput.indexOf(operationSymbol);
    ArrayList<String> clickedNumbers = new ArrayList<String>();
    System.out.println(operation + " index: " + operationIndex);
    for (int i = 0; i < operationIndex; i++) {
      clickedNumbers.add(userInput.get(i));         }
    double double1 = calculator.stringToDouble(String.join("", clickedNumbers)); 
    System.out.println("double1: " + double1);
    clickedNumbers.clear();
    int equalsIndex = userInput.indexOf("=");
    for (int i = operationIndex + 1; i < equalsIndex; i++) {
      clickedNumbers.add(userInput.get(i));
    }
    double double2 = calculator.stringToDouble(String.join("", clickedNumbers)); 
    System.out.println("double2: " + double2);
    Double operResult = this.doOperation(double1, double2);
    String operationResult = calculator.doubleToString(operResult);
    System.out.println("Operation Result: " + operationResult);
    return operationResult;
}
```

All `System.out.println()` statements depend on local variables inside the method. These are what should be printing out to the console only once. Whenever the user puts in an operation and presses equals, for example, if s/he inputs `15 * 3`, it outputs:

[image: Output of Console with desired output highlighted]

Above, the highlighted part of the console output is my desired output.

Here is my code where the `calculate()` method is called:

```Java
  String[] numberStr = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"};
  Boolean pressedEquals = listName.contains("=");

  for(String number : numberStr) {
  Boolean pressedNumber = listName.contains(number);
    if (pressedNumber && pressedEquals) {
      if (listName.contains("+")) {
        processStatement = "Adding Numbers...";
        result = addition.calculate();
      }
      else if (listName.contains("-")) {
        processStatement = "Subtracting Numbers...";
        result = subtraction.calculate();
      }
      else if (listName.contains("*")) {
        processStatement = "Multiplying Numbers...";
        result = multiplication.calculate();
      }
      else if (listName.contains("/")) {
        processStatement = "Dividing Numbers...";
        result = division.calculate();
      }
      else if (listName.contains("%")) {
        processStatement = "Modulufying Numbers...";
        result = modulus.calculate();
      }
      else if (listName.contains("^")) {
        processStatement = "Expounding numbers...";
        result = exponential.calculate();
      }
    } 
  }
```

---

I don't understand why it is printing output as many times as the length of the `userInput` `ArrayList`. I know the problem is the `pressedNumber` Boolean in the `for` loop. I know the OP on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35108386/python-printing-function-output-multiple-times) had the same problem, with it the printing a number of times depending on a length of user input, but the answer to the question did not explain why it was doing this.

### Research and Trials that didn't work

Part of fixing this was making the `processStatement` into a variable because earlier I just printed it inside the condition. This didn't work because it printed multiple times. I cannot do this for the `println` statements inside the method because they depend on the variables inside the method, and there are quite a few statements. My second plan was to make a static method `printInfo()`, but this also wouldn't have worked because of the variables being too tightly scoped, and I can't define them outside because then that would be inaccurate.

#### Update

I have looked more on stack overflow, this time for regular expressions, and  these questions added to my research to solve this problem:

- [This one for making the regular expression that I am looking for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1631820/regular-expression-to-match-digits-and-basic-math-operators)
- [This question for checking if the expression matches the regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23550455/java-regular-expression-for-checking-validity-of-variable-name?rq=1)
- [This question to extract a part of the `regEx` for later code (my control flow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237061/using-regular-expressions-to-extract-a-value-in-java)
- [The answer to this question that makes characters with special meaning be used as regular characters by prepending them with `\\`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3674930/java-regex-meta-character-and-ordinary-dot)

Comment: Well, from a pure Java perspective, it makes no sense to print something once if you're called inside a loop.  The solution is to not print anything at all and have the calling code, not the function, do the printing.

Comment: The better question to ask is "Why is the function being called multiple times in a loop?"

Comment: @markspace Can you explain more in an answer?

Comment: @markspace It is supposed to only print once because the print statement is called under a condition in a loop. The condition contains the counter for the loop (`number`).

Comment: By the way, I strongly recommend to follow the Java Naming Conventions: variable names and methods always start with lowercase. So `ClickedNumbers` should be `clickedNumbers` and `StringToDouble` should be `stringToDouble`.

Comment: @MCEmperor okay, I will change that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few things that you might want to reconsider in your code:

For example, take a look at this snippet:

```
String[] numberStr = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"};
Boolean pressedEquals = listName.contains("=");

for(String number : numberStr) {
    Boolean pressedNumber = listName.contains(number);
    // ...
}
```

You don't need this loop here. You can simply validate the `listName` that it contains digits, operators or not i.e. it is a valid expression. And, then simply call the `calculate()` method if it is valid. You may also use regex-based validation to enforce your particular expression format.

Skipping that loop and after performing validation, it would look like this:

```
// Validate expression format here
// Example: <number> <operator> <number> <=>
//             1          *        5      =

final boolean isValidated = isValidExpression( /* expression */ );

if ( isValidated == true )
{
    final String op = /* get operator here */;
    switch ( op )
    {
        case "+":
            result = addition.calculate();
            break;

        case "-":
            result = subtraction.calculate();
            break;

       // ... /, *, % ...

        default:
            // ERROR: Invalid operator...
    }
}
```

Apart from this, you may use stack-based expression evaluation too.

---

**UPDATE:**

Here's an example of `isValidExpression()` method with regex:

```
// Test to validate expression with regex
// Example: <number> <operator> <number> <=>
//             1          *        5      =

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

class ExpressionValidator
{
    public static boolean isValidExpression( final String exp )
    {
        final String regex = "\\d+\\s*[*|/|+|-]\\s*\\d+\\s*[=]";
        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile( regex );
        final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher( exp.trim() );
        return matcher.find();
    }

    public static void main( final String[] args )
    {
        final String[] expressions = 
        {  
            " 1 +  2 =",
            " 3 *  5 =",
            "12 + 10 =",
            " 33 = 25 ",
            " +65  65 ",
            "45 666  ="
        };

        for ( final String exp : expressions )
        {
            System.out.println( "[" + exp + "] >> " + isValidExpression( exp ) );
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[ 1 +  2 =] >> true
[ 3 *  5 =] >> true
[12 + 10 =] >> true
[ 33 = 25 ] >> false
[ +65  65 ] >> false
[45 666  =] >> false
```

Here's the live example: https://ideone.com/S9Wf9b

Comment: Thanks for the answer Azeem. I looked it up and it seems validateExpression is not an actual method, so, would I have to make my own function for this? If it is, would I just type `return `<number> <operator> <number <=>`? Also, I would not use `final String op` in here because I already have it in my `calculate` method.

Comment: Error: **calculator.pde:115:0:115:0: The function validateExpression(String) does not exist**. I put in the following code `String listString = String.join(", ", listName);
  final boolean isValidated = validateExpression(listString);

  if (isValidated == true) {
    if (listName.contains("+")) {`

Comment: @Marvin : That was just an idea. You have to write your own validation function. You can use regular expression of Java.

Comment: can you explain in your answer how to use regular expression since I have never used them before. Or point me to a link online. I couldn't find any tutorials on RegEx syntax. Thanks

Comment: @Marvin: I've added an example to validate the input expression using regex. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you very much! This helps! However, the user needs to be able to put in as many decimals as they want. Is there a way to make all decimals digits optional including the '.'?

Comment: @Marvin : You are welcome! Honestly, using regex for such parsing problems is not the optimal way. You ought to consider writing your own parser. I believe you'll find some good ones online too. For this small trivial problem, it is okay though I would separate the regex compile part in the static block for optimization.

Comment: `public static boolean validateExpression(String exp ) {
  // Reg Ex: - or + one or more numbers . oe or more numbers operator same thing
  String regex = "([-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+[\/\+\-\*])+([-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+)";
  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile( regex );
  Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher( exp.trim() );
  return matcher.find();
}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178761/discussion-between-marvin-and-azeem).